# Understanding this Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Found this while learning on a tutorial, having trouble understanding it, as the source code gives no comment on what it is doing. I passed many different byte[] values to it to see if I can figure it out, I can't. And most Lambda tutorials only show a single variable type - not 2.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

private string DoLamdaExpression(byte[] data)
{
    var intData = data.Aggregate<byte, BigInteger>(0, (current, t) => current * 256 + t);
    string result = intData.ToString();
    return result;
}
```

current and t are not defined anywhere previously so honestly, I do not know what the role of "byte[] data" is being used other than calling the `.Aggregate` function.

additionally data.Aggregate = the Accumulate function...
my gut feeling is that "byte" is taking the role of current, and "BigInteger" is taking the role of t.

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func);
```

Comment: It interprets the array of bytes as if it was one large arbitrarily sized integer (with big endian byte order)

Comment: just a less efficient for loop https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ff1369203d6036a4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lambda expression defines an anonymous `Func` that aggregates the `data` byte array, where each element of the array is processed. `current` represents the result so far and `t` is the element being processed. In this example, the function iterates the array, and for each element, multiplies the current result by 256 and adds the element being handled.

Comment: Ahh! Eureka! if 01 is used data[] = 4849, 48 * 256 + 49 = 12337. Thankyou that makes sense now